# shrink algorithm

Tags: multicol, algorithm2e, resize

I am writing a 2-column paper. I have 2 algorithms each within `\begin{multicols} ... \end{multicols}` environment. I want to scale each of them to half the size so that I can fit it side-by-side. How do I do it? I cannot use scalebox or resizebox as they are throwing `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` error.

Right now the MWE I have is as follows

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}
\SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
\SetKwProg{Proc}{Proc}{\string:}{}
\SetKwProg{Call}{Call}{\string;}{}
\SetKwProg{Algo}{Algo}{\string:}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{\string:}{}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{fintq}%
\newcommand{\forcond}{$i=0$ \KwTo $n$}
\renewcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
\AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoEnd\SetAlgoNoLine%

\Input{some $i$} 
%(reward function assume given)}

\Algo{Algorithm 1}

\Call{Function 1}

\While {something} {
    \Foreach{other things}{
        \eIf {at all anything} {
            do something
             } { %else part
            do something else }

    \Call{Function 2}

    do more stuff\;

    \Foreach{many things}{
        do x, y, z
    }
}
}

\Proc{Function 1}

$x = y +z $\;

\Foreach{$x$}{
    do something to each $x$
    \Foreach{$y$}{
    do something to $y$
    }
}

\vspace*{0.25cm}

\Proc{Function 2}

\Foreach{$z$}{
        initialize something 

        \Foreach{$z \times z$} {
            \If{$z^2 > 4$} {
                it is greater than 4\;
                add 9}
        }
    }
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\caption{Sample Algorithm}
\label{samplealgo}
\end{algorithm*}

\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}
\SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
\SetKwProg{Proc}{Proc}{\string:}{}
\SetKwProg{Call}{Call}{\string;}{}
\SetKwProg{Algo}{Algo}{\string:}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{\string:}{}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{fintq}%
\newcommand{\forcond}{$i=0$ \KwTo $n$}
\renewcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
\AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoEnd\SetAlgoNoLine%

\Input{some more inputs} 
%(reward function assume given)}

\Algo{Algorithm 2}

\Call{Function 1}

\While {something} {
    \Foreach{other things}{
        \eIf {at all anything} {
            do something
             } { %else part
            do something else }

    \Call{Function 2}

    do more stuff\;

    \Foreach{many things}{
        do x, y, z
    }
}
}

\Proc{Function 1}

$x = y +z $\;

\Foreach{$x$}{
    do something to each $x$
    \Foreach{$y$}{
    do something to $y$
    }
}

\vspace*{0.25cm}

\Proc{Function 2}

\Foreach{$z$}{
        initialize something 

        \Foreach{$z \times z$} {
            \If{$z^2 > 4$} {
                it is greater than 4\;
                add 9}
        }
    }
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\caption{Sample 2 Algorithm}
\label{samplealgo}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

I cannot use `\begin{multicols}{4} ... \end{multicols}` since the text in the algorithm is much larger than 1/4 of the page. Hence I HAVE to use resizebox or something equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps a minipage inside each column Will do the trick.  (You can put a scaled box in there.)

Comment: With multicols package, I cannot specify the column explicitly. So, can you help me how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good deal of dirty tricks!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure*}% for getting a float
\begingroup % trick algorithm2e into thinking we're in one column mode
\csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
\noindent
\resizebox{.49\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}
\SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
\SetKwProg{Proc}{Proc}{\string:}{}
\SetKwProg{Call}{Call}{\string;}{}
\SetKwProg{Algo}{Algo}{\string:}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{\string:}{}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{fintq}%
\newcommand{\forcond}{$i=0$ \KwTo $n$}
\renewcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
\AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoEnd\SetAlgoNoLine%

\Input{some $i$} 
%(reward function assume given)}

\Algo{Algorithm 1}

\Call{Function 1}

\While {something} {
    \Foreach{other things}{
        \eIf {at all anything} {
            do something
             } { %else part
            do something else }

    \Call{Function 2}

    do more stuff\;

    \Foreach{many things}{
        do x, y, z
    }
}
}

\Proc{Function 1}

$x = y +z $\;

\Foreach{$x$}{
    do something to each $x$
    \Foreach{$y$}{
    do something to $y$
    }
}

\vspace*{0.25cm}

\Proc{Function 2}

\Foreach{$z$}{
        initialize something 

        \Foreach{$z \times z$} {
            \If{$z^2 > 4$} {
                it is greater than 4\;
                add 9}
        }
    }
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\caption{Sample Algorithm}
\label{samplealgo}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
}% <------------- end of \resizebox
\hfill
\resizebox{.49\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\SetStartEndCondition{ }{}{}%
\SetKwProg{Fn}{def}{\string:}{}
\SetKwFunction{Range}{range}%%
\SetKwProg{Proc}{Proc}{\string:}{}
\SetKwProg{Call}{Call}{\string;}{}
\SetKwProg{Algo}{Algo}{\string:}{}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{For}{for}{\string:}{}%
\SetKw{KwTo}{in}\SetKwFor{Foreach}{for each}{\string:}{}%
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{elif}{else:}{}%
\SetKwFor{While}{while}{:}{fintq}%
\newcommand{\forcond}{$i=0$ \KwTo $n$}
\renewcommand{\forcond}{$i$ \KwTo\Range{$n$}}
\AlgoDontDisplayBlockMarkers\SetAlgoNoEnd\SetAlgoNoLine%

\Input{some more inputs} 
%(reward function assume given)}

\Algo{Algorithm 2}

\Call{Function 1}

\While {something} {
    \Foreach{other things}{
        \eIf {at all anything} {
            do something
             } { %else part
            do something else }

    \Call{Function 2}

    do more stuff\;

    \Foreach{many things}{
        do x, y, z
    }
}
}

\Proc{Function 1}

$x = y +z $\;

\Foreach{$x$}{
    do something to each $x$
    \Foreach{$y$}{
    do something to $y$
    }
}

\vspace*{0.25cm}

\Proc{Function 2}

\Foreach{$z$}{
        initialize something 

        \Foreach{$z \times z$} {
            \If{$z^2 > 4$} {
                it is greater than 4\;
                add 9}
        }
    }
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{0.25cm}
\caption{Sample 2 Algorithm}
\label{samplealgo}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}%
}% <------------- end of \resizebox
\endgroup
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[4-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @egreg, surprisingly, following many other threads, and building one top of one another I came up with a very similar solution, using `\scalebox` instead of `\resizebox`!

Comment: `\minipage` inside `\resizebox` is a true lifesaver, thanks!